# Formula for showing more liked items more often than less liked items with a random factor

Tags: mysql, math, formula, probability, popularity

in mysql currently I am using `order by RAND() DESC`
which works fine
except i also have a number that counts number of likes which ranges from 0 to 5 right now but 5 could increase in the future let's call 5 my `maxlikes`

How can order it in such a way that the ones with more likes has more probability of showing up more often but still randomly show the ones with fewer likes from time to time?

Comment: I ended up selecting a `max(rand()) as my order` when i count likes so that each like gives it an equal chance of showing up so the items with a lot of likes can have multiple opportunity to get a high (like each like is like a lottery ticket kind'a idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `order by RAND()*likes DESC` favors highly liked things
or something like `order by RAND()*maxLikes +Likes DESC` add maxLikes/2 on average to rank

it really depends on what you want the distribution to be
I think you could also
`select columns, rankingFormulaWithRandom as rank .... order by rank desc`

Comment: I didn't use this because distribution is too much in favor of liked, i wanted a like to act like an extra entry so i selected `max(rand()) as my order` on the same line when i count my likes so that the ones with many likes get multiple opportunity to get high rank (but keeping everything equal like extra entries in a random lottery).